# SVM kernels corresponding to different types of distance measures

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, svm

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141775/110833) to [*Data normalization for RBF kernel*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/141751/110833) points out that RBF kernel implies Eucledean distance. Are there kernels corresponding to other popular distance/dissimilarity measures, such as Bray-Curtis or Jensen-Shannon? Or could they be easily designed? What are the constraints to take into account (e.g., does Bray-Curtis pose a problem because of its non-analiticity?)

Related: [*About Gaussian kernel for distances other than Euclidian*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/509640/110833)

Comment: Bray-Curtis dissimilarity isn't a distance because it doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality. In any event, the thing that you care about for the purposes of SVM is that the kernel matrix is *symmetric* and *positive definite* for distinct inputs.

Comment: @Sycorax I corrected the question accordingly. If using a real distance is a constraint for kernel trick, this could be the beginning of an answer to the last part of the question.